# Is there a middleware for Expressjs that dumps every request to console?

Tags: express

here is what I'm doing :

```
router.get('/test123', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.originalUrl)
  res.send(200)
})
```

is there a generic middle way to dump the originalUrl for every route in an Express App? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  next();
});
```

Make sure you declare that middleware before any of your routes.